# Different results in asio client application when passing a variable or putting an ip string with the same content

Tags: c++, client, boost-asio

There's something I'm unable to figure out.
Below is a part of the code from the chat client example from boost asio: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp

```
int Tcp::client(std::string peer_ip)
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(peer_ip, "1975");
        
        chat_client c(io_context, endpoints);

        std::thread t([&io_context]() { io_context.run(); });
        
        char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
        while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
        {
          chat_message msg;
          msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
          std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
          msg.encode_header();
          c.write(msg);
        }

        c.close();
        t.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the peer_ip variable is passed to the resolver as above, then I get:
Exception: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)

```
auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(peer_ip, "1975");
```

And if the string of the ip address is given as below, then the client works and talks to the server.

```
auto endpoints = resolver.resolve("13.58.174.105", "1975");
```

I also tried passing a const variable and a reference, make the variabel std::move, but somehow my efforts didn't work out.

Do you know where the problem lies and what I should do?

TIA,
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of the `peer_ip` variable? If it's also "13.58.174.105" **then** it would be weird.

Otherwise it simply means that the host name cannot be resolved to the IP address.

If `peer_ip` is known to always contain an IP address, there is **no need to resolve anything anyways** and you can just **parse** the address instead:

```
std::string peer_ip = "127.0.0.1";
tcp::endpoint endpoint {
    boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(peer_ip.c_str()), 1975 };
```

Comment: The peer_ip variable has the same string like "127.0.0.1". The endpoints variable in the chat example is a tcp::resolver::results_type and not a tcp::endpoint, I also did try boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string.

Comment: Well like I said "If it's also "13.58.174.105" then it would be weird." By that point I would only check that the string is actually correct. E.g. just delete it and type it again, just making sure it doesn't contain weird UNICODE characters or a hidden space or things like that.

Comment: This is the culprit, both strings look similar, but somehow they aren't.

Comment: One string comes from a json file and there's something wrong with that string

Comment: @NicoVerrijdt Hehe. Isn't it always like this. 80% of a programmer's life is checking input and doubting assumptions :) Glad you found it

Answer (score -1):

std::string Tcp::client(std::string peer_ip) { try { boost::asio::io_context io_context; tcp::resolver resolver(io_context); auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(peer_ip, "1975"); p2p_client c(io_context, endpoints); std::thread t(&io_context { io_context.run(); }); char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1]; while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1)) { chat_message msg; msg.body_length(std::strlen(line)); std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length()); msg.encode_header(); c.write(msg); } c.close(); t.join(); } catch (std::exception &e) { std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n"; } return 0; } peer_ip

Comment: what happened? Did you mean to add text here? It's unclear how this answers the question and the formatting should be fixed.